# Fedora Server Allow download link to PDF files

Tags: php, fedora

I have a website hosted on Fedora and I need my users to beable to download PDF files, is there any mod_rewrtie I can use to only allow PDF's to be downloaded, at the moment it just goes to 404 page.

Cheers

J

Comment: This question is regarding server configuration. It should have been asked at ServerFault.com, StackOverflow's sibling site for server-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use tail -f /var/log/httpd/* for get the httpd error message

Answer (score 0):

How about only putting .PDFs on the server if that's all it does?